# Fastest way of checking if a subgraph is a clique in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I want to find out if a given subgraph of G is a complete graph. I was expecting to find a built in function, like `is_complete_graph(G)`, but I can't see anything like that.

My current solution is to create a new helper function:

```
def is_complete(G):
    n = G.order()
    return n*(n-1)/2 == G.size()
```

I imagine this is probably fast but I feel wrong implementing this kind of thing myself, and I feel there must be a 'right' way to do it in NetworkX.

I only need a solution for simple undirected graphs.

Comment: Don't use `/` for integer division, use `//` instead.  Python 3 will convert integers to float if you use `/`, whereas `//` works in both Python 2 and 3, producing an integer result for integer operands.

Comment: It looks like using this function will require you to build a new graph which is the subgraph of your original.  Unless you need to build that new graph anyways there will be faster ways that don't require you to create a separate new graph.  Can you tell us if you need to build the new graph for some other purpose?

Comment: @Joel No I don't actually need the subgraph for anything else. So something like `G.has_clique(t)` would be great

Comment: @TomKarzes Interesting Tom, I didn't know that. I'm hesitant to use the `//` operator though because for me it implies to the reader that some sort of rounding is taking place, which it isn't (since n is an int `n*(n-1)` is guaranteed to be even). It's a cool optimisation though that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @bubsy_revelations No, it just means it's doing integer division rather than floating point.  In fact, it's the opposite from your claim:  Floating point division implies that the result is *not* an integer, since otherwise you would certainly use integer division.  Using floating point arithmetic  is inappropriate.  Note that if you used Python 2, it *would* do integer division.  It was only in Python 3 that it was changed, so your code is also incompatible between the two versions.  Using `//` would fix that as well.

Comment: What kind of graph is it?  (simple, directed, multi,..)

Comment: @Joel I just need a solution for simple undirected graphs with no self-loops. Thanks :)

Comment: @TomKarzes In my experience people only use the `//` for rounding, not for integer division. This is how it used in [networkx itself](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/connectivity/connectivity.py), for instance. I'm using Python because I value clarity and simplicity over optimisation. There would be no difference at all with Python 2 and 3 since as I've said, the result is guaranteed to be an integer and I'm not using values large enough to introduce floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: @bubsy_revelations Floating point numbers and integers are different types.  You are confusing truncation with type conversion.  While it is true that `1.0` compares equal to `1`, the two values are different.  Look at `type(1.0)` and `type(1)`.  They are different.  Different data types.  For your application, you do not want to convert the values to `float`.  You want to keep them as integers.  That is why `//` is the correct operator to use.

Comment: @bubsy_revelations At the very least, you would want to convert the result back to an integer data type, so you would do `int(a // b)`.  But oh, wait, that's just `a // b`.  If you are performing arithmetic on two integers that produces an integer result, *always* do it as integer arithmetic, never as floating point.  The type of a value matters.

Comment: @bubsy_revelations I think maybe you're confusing `a // b` with `floor(a / b)`.  The latter produces a float result, and simply discards the fractional portion.  You would be doing floating point division, then truncating the result.  Not integer division.  The `//` operator, with integer operands, is pure integer division.  The values remain as integers, and the result is *exact*.  You would never convert the values to floating point, perform floating point division, and then leave then as floating point as your code does.

Comment: @bubsy_revelations Oh, and to show you why your code behaves differently under Python 2 vs. Python 3, try the following in each:  `print(2/1)`.  Python 2 prints `2`, which has an integer data type.  Python 3, on the other hand, produces a floating point result and prints `2.0`, because the result is a float, not an integer.

Comment: @TomKarzes I do understand, I just disagree (against conventional wisdom, it seems). I'm a fan of just treating numbers as numbers in python, without thinking of the underlying type.

I also don't want to hide errors. Say there was a problem with my code and the result of the division was not an integer. Then `//` would round it down and could hide the problem.

Comment: @bubsy_revelations Just keep in mind that when an experienced programmer sees you dividing two integer types to produce a floating point result, they will make the natural assumption that the result is *not* always expected to be an integer, since otherwise you wouldn't use floating point to represent the result.  I.e., the exact opposite of what you intend to convey.  They will also likely fix it, or rewrite it altogether.  Note that Python 2 will not give you a floating point result, even with the `/` operator, unless you explicitly convert one of the operands to float first.

Answer (score 3):

**edit**

The answer at the bottom is relatively clean.  However, it appears that the following is faster:

```
def is_subclique(G,nodelist):
    H = G.subgraph(nodelist)
    n = len(nodelist)
    return H.size() == n*(n-1)/2
```

I have to admit, I don't entirely understand.  But clearly creating the subgraph is faster than checking whether each edge exists.

---

Slower alternative I expected to be faster:

We'll check to see if all of the edges are there.  We'll use `combinations` to generate the pairs we check.  Note that if `combinations` returns `(1,2)`, then it will not return `(2,1)`.

```
from itertools import combinations
import networkx as nx

def is_subclique(G, nodelist):
    r'''For each pair of nodes in nodelist whether there is an edge
        if any edge is missing, we know that it's not a subclique.
        if all edges are there, it is a subclique
    '''
    for (u,v) in combinations(nodelist,2):  #check each possible pair
        if not G.has_edge(u,v):
            return False #if any edge is missing we're done
    return True  #if we get to here, then every edge was there.  It's True.

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3), (3,1), (4,1)])

is_subclique(G, [1,2,3])
> True
is_subclique(G, [1,4])
> True
is_subclique(G, [2,3,4])
> False
```

Comment: Hi Joel. Thanks for answering my question!

I have done some comparison between this function and my original one. [See my code here](https://pastebin.com/m6Jj8tHE). I found that for graphs with around 200 nodes, this implementation was slower by many orders of magnitude, due to the explosive growth of the combination.

Comment: Even for graphs with about 10 nodes this implementation is slower by an order of magnitude or so. I think the cost of creating a new graph is outweighed by the cost of iterating over the edges in this way. Perhaps this would be better if dealing with very small graphs when memory is constrained? But for my use case, the implementation in the question is still the best.

Comment: That surprises me.  I assume you're using the `subgraph` command in networkx?  I had thought that it generated the subgraph using something like the loop I did, but now that I look at the source code it's doing something else, which I guess is a lot faster.  Given what you're saying, I think your implementation is probably the best.

Comment: OK, hanks for your help. Was hoping to get a solution built into networkx but if that isn't available then I doubt I'll get a suitable answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to check more than the number of edges because selfloops aren't allowed for a complete_graph. Also, they potentially change the expected count of edges.

Here's a very fast function -- especially if it isn't a complete graph. Notice that it avoids even counting the edges. It just makes sure each node has the right neighbors.

```
def is_complete_graph(G):
    N = len(G) - 1
    return not any(n in nbrdict or len(nbrdict)!=N for n, nbrdict in G.adj.items())
```